# What is a good workflow for 'cherry-picking' branches for deployment?

Tags: svn, deployment

We have a situation where we're using SVN and developers have branches for features that we want to implement as well as defects to be fixed and sometimes experimental branches or spikes.

We also have a 'staging' branch that indicates the current state of the staging server.

In the process of deploying to the staging server, **we have to determine what is ready to go to staging and what is not.** Currently this is done by asking each developer and trusting that they will remember what features or bugs are ready to be pushed up, sometimes from a few weeks ago.

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, but I'm not sure which way to go:

1. when a developer completes an item and it's ready for staging, put
   it in a tags folder like /tags/readyforstaging/? Then move the contents after each deployment into something like /tags/archive/? (but will this mess with the revision history?)
2. Same idea as #1, but create a new root folder to avoid confusion with the static nature of tags, like /ready/staging/ and /ready/archive/?

I'm not sure we can have developers merge into staging directly because we may not want their feature to be in the next deployment for whatever reason.

**Does anyone know a good way to do this so we have an unambiguous list of everything that is ready to go but doesnt wreak havoc with revision history/graphs?**

Answer (score 0):

It's anyway not "good way", but at least it work in real projects

In case of **strict** "Branch Per Task" policy you can use "Unstable Trunk" game:

- Trunk have **only mergesets** from task-branches (author have to merge finished own branches into trunk, integration tests must be performed after each merge, fixes to branch in question applied and re-merges performed *if needed*)
- For clean, well-readable history of trunk none of reverse merges must be added into trunk (when integration-test failed, before fix), "Ready4Staging" can be additional special URL in repo and must be a single authoritative source for merging to Staging branch